# Receiving tesseract does not interact with build-craft transport pipes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-thermal-expansion

Almost on every tutorial video, I watched about `Thermal Expansion` tesseracts, receiving one can output items to build craft transport pipes (gold or stone). The thing is I use `Thermal Expansion 3.0.0.2` mod which has only one type of tesseracts (Not energy, fluid and item like was earlier. Now it's three in one.). And the problem is that receiving tesseract does not output items to transport pipes. It can easily interact with any kind of chests attached directly to it (even with `Applied Energistics chests`), but not with the pipes. What am I doing wrong or how to fix this? The following configuration does not work:

**Sending tesseract:**
[image]

**Receiving tesseract:**
[image]

But if I put chest directly to the receiving tesseract items are transported properly. The next configuration works fine:
[image]
[image]

I use **Minecraft 1.6.4**, **Thermal Expansion 3.0.0.2** and **Build Craft 4.2.2**. Client and server are combined by myself and all mods are installed on vanilla minecraft. No additional modpacks were used. Here is **[full list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edGd4RE9GcEZvdEhSVFBLYTVQemEwWXc&usp=sharing#gid=1)** of mods I installed.

**EDIT:**
I started new client only with 3 mods from **[this list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edGd4RE9GcEZvdEhSVFBLYTVQemEwWXc&usp=sharing#gid=1)**: **BuildCraft**, **Thermal Expansion** and **NEI** and nothing changed. Receiving tesseract still doesn't pump out item to the pipes.

Comment: Wild guess, can't check it since I'm at work, but is it possible that your wooden pipes are connected the wrong way? (I don't even know if that's possible) What happens if you put some items in the chests? Do they get pulled out? Are the autarchic gates on your pipes set correctly to output a redstone pulse?

Comment: @Arperum, wooden piper re connected correctly: left one pumps items from chest, right one from tesseract (ideally items should not be pumped from tesseract). When I pull out items from left chest they travel through wooden pipe and then are thrown out to the world. (There is some cobblestone floating around on the screen shot.) But when I put chest directly to the receiving tesseract - items are transported correctly. I added another screen shot for clarity.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm intrigued now. I might install these mods tonight and check them out. ping me [in Minecraft talk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk) or [in The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) if I haven't come back to it in 8-10 hours.

Comment: Based on the screenshots I can see at least AE, NEI, Enderstorage, betterstorage(the one that adds the metal chests) and some minimap mod in there. Is this some custom made modpack or did you combine some mods yourself? So I can test in exactly the same situation.

Comment: @Arperum, all mods are combined by myself and installed on clean vanilla minecraft. At the moment there are 76 mods (with children and dependencies). And [this is](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edGd4RE9GcEZvdEhSVFBLYTVQemEwWXc&usp=sharing) full list of mods installed (1.6.4 tab). Green ones are installed, red ones I don't want to install and other ones I plan to install.

Comment: Hmmm, going to start out with a way smaller list. WHat version of Forge are you using.

Comment: @Arperum, I've just created new mod pack only with NEI, BuildCraft and ThermalExpansion and tried it in singleplayer - the same behavior. I use Forge 9.11.1.965.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use a wooden pipe connected to the output tesseract. Have you tried using other types of pipe?

Comment: @JLaBella, on the first and second screen shots I use Three different pipes - gold, stone and wooden with gate. None of them are working. I also tried them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that they are not compatible with buildcrafts pipes yet, you need to use a fluiduct(you're free to use a pipe after that i think).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without using a wooden transport pipe (connecting your gold / stone transport pipes directly to the tesseract)?  I ask because certain machines do not require a wooden transport pipe to pull items out, they push to pipes themselves, and a wooden transport pipe would actually hinder their ability to do so.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do that. Possibly, as tomiesz said, tesseracts and build craft pipes are not compatible yet.